# I need help unbanning youtube

Tags: lubuntu, youtube

I'm a noob and I'll admit it.  A while ago this computer was my sisters and I found her viewing some very inappropriate youtube videos for her age.  So I had a friend with technical knowledge disable youtube for this computer...  And now that she no longer owns this computer I'd like to re-enable it, But I cannot get in touch with this friend any longer.  I do not know what he did to ban it I just know it IS inside the computer system and not the network.

When I go to "Youtube.com" it returns "Index of /" Trying "https://www.youtube.com" returns "Problem loading page"

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/hosts`.

Comment: See my answer and give me a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `hosts` file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

And remove the YouTube entries.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Yep, Just have to wait a few more minutes.